Is it possible to break when RDX changes to a certain value?
I have a bug in my code where rdx = 0x1111111111111111 and is then dereferenced leading to memory access violation. I can catch this using a first chance exception
Address=00000000C0000005
Module/Label/Exception=EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
State=Enabled
Hits=1
Summary=firstchance()

I want to find when this register is first set to this value to determine the root cause (maybe there is a better way). My language is interpreted (vba, injecting assembly code, although the error doesn't happen in my injected function) so the call-stack leading up to the exception is not very helpful.
I have tried to use x64dbg's "watchdog" but that seems trigger on the same instruction where the rdx read occurs, not the one that sets rdx.
00007FFB10751E5A                              | 48:8B52 08               | mov rdx,qword ptr ds:[rdx+8]                            |

Watchdog Watch 6 (expression "rdx==0x1111111111111111") is triggered at 00007FFB10751E5A ! Original value: 0000000000000000, New value: 0000000000000001
Exception Breakpoint EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (00000000C0000005) at 00007FFB10751E5A!
Watchdog Watch 6 (expression "rdx==0x1111111111111111") is triggered at 00007FFB10751E5A ! Original value: 0000000000000001, New value: 0000000000000001

I cannot figure out how to set a breakpoint triggered by changes to rdx that have a certain value.
Name=Watch 6
Expression=rdx==0x1111111111111111
Value=0000000000000001
Type=UINT
Watchdog Mode=Is true
ID=6

